# Remove / hide browser generated "Waiting for someapicall.com..." in lower left corner?

Tags: javascript, api, google-chrome, browser, airtable

Is there a way to hide this "Waiting for..." alert during an api call? It shows up in the lower left corner of Chrome roughly where you see URLs when you hover links.

It seems browser-specific because I see it in Chrome but not in Firefox. Is it specific to api.airtable?

I have no idea where to begin researching this.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is a way to remove it. According to W3Schools, there was: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_win_status.asp

It used to be called `window.status`. I think they removed it for a security reason. Now, no browsers support it. I even checked `jsfiddle.net` and it didn't work for Chrome. However, it is supported in Opera 12 and before. If you would like to set it in that:

```js
window.status = "";
```

For other purposes, `window.status` still updates when the status has changed in the bottom left. That means you can read this bar, but you can't write to it.

However, as [`user13861136` said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62843581/13514657), you can add an `aria-label=""` to prevent it from appearing when hovering onto the respective element. This, however, won't work when the HTML file is being requested.

If you want to remove it from when you hover on `<a>` tags, then you can simply remove the `href` attribute and replace it with an onclick, which will run either `window.open('https://example.com/')` or `window.location.href='https://example.com/'` or something else if your `target` attribute is different. This will, however, remove all the browser defaults for the tag. This can be fixed by adding an empty `href` attribute like this: `href=""`.

### [`JSFiddle`](https://jsfiddle.net/hmodyc7p/)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You Unfortunately cannot remove this, this is permanent to every browser application, it also protects you from getting rickrolled.. However i think you can fix this with `aria-label=“”`

Comment: on what element(s)?

Comment: the Html like this `<p aria-label=“” href=“”></p>` (I put `p` as an example) i also recommend putting the `href=“”` label it sets the “link” unlike `<a></a>` it doesn’t send you somewhere when you click it. `aria-label=“”` and `href=“”` can be used any where. this will likely set it to nothing when you hover over the element